# Move, Resize an image in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Is there a way to put an image (png) in a QGraphicsScene, move and resize it with the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a *Diagram Scene* example which should give you an idea how to do it:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html

For adding an image into a `QGraphicsScene`, use [`QGraphicsPixmapItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html)